# Turbo-Rails with Devise does not redirect Consistently Rails 6.1.3 Devise 4.7.3 Turbo Rails 0.5.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, turbo-rails

THIS IS A COMPANION TO https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/122

REPRODUCTION APP CODE: https://github.com/jasonfb/TR001

Using
**Rails 6.1.3**

**Devise  4.7.3**

**Turbo Rails 0.5.9**

---

**Symptom 1**:
-- using Turbo-Rails + Devise

When I click "Log In", the form submits but the page does not reload.

Step 1: go to

/users/sign_in

Enter a good username & password (you can sign up or make one on the command line)

[image]

Click "Sign In"

[image]

on the back end the request WAS processed and even redirected, but the redirect did not happen on the front end. You (the user) **ARE** actually logged in even though your page is hanging and did not redirect.

[image]

Result: Page hangs.
Expected result: Turbo Rails redirect correctly

---

**Symptom 2**

When I click "Log Out", the page does nothing.
on the backend I am actually logged out, but the page does not change.
If I reload, I see that I am now logged out

Step 1: be logged in

Step 2: Click to "log out"
[image]

Notice that the button stays 'grey' (clicked), the request is processed on the back end:

[image]

Result: Page hangs

Expected result: Page directs after the user is logged out

The user IS ACTUALLY logged out, but the page hangs and does not redirect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This  has been fixed on the Devise main branch, but as of 2021-12-29 there is not a released version of Devise for Rails 7. If you want to use the latest main branch of Devise from Github, this problem should not affect you.

**TEMPORARY WORKAROUND**:

override the devise form (use rails generate devise:views generating your own custom views

then you will edit the registrations/new and sessions/new modifying both like so:

```rb
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name) ) do |f|
```

change it to

```rb
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, html: {'data-turbo' => "false"}, url: session_path(resource_name) ) do |f|
```

this tells Devise to fall back to non-Turbo interaction for the log-in and registration.

**For your Logout links use Rails button_to instead of link_to and the symptom goes away.**
note: recommend as a temporary fix until the root cause is addressed

**Again, button_to for LOGGING OUT must be like so:**

```
, method: :delete, 'data-turbo': false
```

alternatively, a nested syntax like `data: { turbo: false }` should also work for either form_for or button_to

Comment: button_to didn't work in my case.

Comment: maybe the button_to wasn't producing a form with a POST method? it's because logout should be treated as non-idempotent, which means it must be a POST and not a GET, or else you see the symptom.

Comment: fixed by adding this to button: `form: { "data-turbo" => "false" }`, issue may come from tubo rails.

Comment: I see the PR hasn't been merged yet so I'm trying to disable Turbo on my Devise forms like you have in the above answer but even that doesn't seem to stop them from `Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM`.  Was there something else that you changed in addition to adding `html: {'data-turbo' => "false"}` to the `form_for` tags?

Comment: @mg87 I did it today and it works correctly, you need to make sure that the position of HTML key is correctly, this is mine: `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'space-y-6', data: { turbo: false } }) do |f| %>`

Comment: button_to has a really funky 4-parameters input. Read the docs of the 4 parameters carefully. Parameters 2 and 3 are optional, but parameter 2 cannot be omitted without parameter 3.  it's rather confusing so I always have to check my HTML output to confirm I've done it right.